# Jmeter,In 'view results in Table',what does Thread name(1-1,1-6..etc)?

Tags: jmeter

I have recorded script and run for 50 users.
I have added listeners like view results in table, summary report and view results tree.

After completion of 50 users,
In View results in Table'->Thread name is shown like below screenshot:
[image: screen]

1. According to my knowledge thread name should be `Thread group 1-1`,`Thread group 1-2`, `thread group 1-3`...etc but here the order is shown different.(ie.,`Thread group 1-1`, `Thread group 1-6`, `thread group 1-45`...etc).

   Please refer screenshot **[threadname.jpeg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0BO78.jpg).**
2. In summary report, how standard deviation calculated? In Wikipedia i have seen the example, but it is general mathematical calculation.

   I want real time example in summary report to calculate standard deviation
3. In summary report, sent and received bytes, average bytes means? Is there any calculation for that?

I am new to Jmeter.

Comment: [Refer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14252570/how-to-analyse-jmeter-result)

Answer (score 1):

Thread group 1-31 means it is the request that belongs to thread group number 1 and the thread number is 31.You can have multiple thread group accessing different parts of your application, then the threadname will be threadgroup 2-31 or 3-31 etc..

Answer (score 0):

1. Order of JMeter threads execution doesn't necessarily has to be sequential, it depends on operating system underlying threads. You can play with [Java HotSpot VM Options](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html) in order to attempt to amend the behaviour, however I don't see any sense in it as default  fixed-priority scheduling algorithm should be good to go. In any case JMeter threads are isolated from each other normally shouldn't communicate so the order of execution doesn't really matter.
2. JMeter calculates standard deviation like electronic sheet processing software does via [STDEVP function](http://www.statisticshowto.com/how-to-find-a-standard-deviation-in-excel-2007-video/), just in case if you need the formula:

   [image: STDEVP formula]
3. - Sent bytes/sec - how many bytes virtual user(s) sent per second (request throughput)
   - Received bytes/sec - how many bytes virtual user(s) received per second (response throughput)
   - Average bytes - [arithmetic mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_mean) of response size(s)

More information:

- [Calulator class source](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/trunk/src/core/org/apache/jmeter/util/Calculator.java) has all the relevant formulae
- Glossaries of JMeter in general and performance testing in particular can be found [here](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207420385-Glossary) and [here](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html#glossary).