# What is the best way to report the test results in JMeter?

Tags: jmeter

After the performance tests of a REST web service, what is the best way to report the test results.
test must be run on non-gui mode for high loads. so gui will be closed while test are executed.
The reports must be readable by customers. So, does the customers have to have Jmeter tool for analyzing the results?
In non gui mode, the listeners can be saved but when we or customers want to examine the results, the Jmeter tool must be opened. Are there any way useful?
Grafana may be used in non gui mode with InfluxDB. But the same issue is still valid.

Comment: there is no best way, only the best way for you.
but take a look at https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html for the generation of html reports from the headless cli

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what do "customers" want to see as the "results" and what do you mean by "the best"

1. It's possible to generate [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html)
2. It's possible to generate tables and charts using either [JMeterPluginsCMD Command Line Tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JMeterPluginsCMD/) and [Graphs Generator Listener](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/GraphsGeneratorListener/)
3. It's possible to use a 3rd-party tool like [Taurus](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/taurus-new-star-test-automation-tools-constellation) which provides [interactive reports in console and in the web](https://gettaurus.org/docs/Reporting/).
4. Other less popular options are listed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14256688/2897748)